# Program that sends e-mails and shows whether the links inside the e-mail were accessed by the recipient

Tags: email

I need an app that enables each user to send e-mails to various recipients, and then shows a confirmation if the (personalized) link inside the e-mail to my own server was accessed by the recipient.

I am imagining a window with a table, which shows in every row a sent e-mail message and whether the link inside was accessed or not. Could an e-mail marketing program have these features?

Do you know such software?

The platform can be Windows or Linux. It would be a plus if the app had the possibility to create multiple users with different access rights.